# Passing value in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-api

I use the Yandex API to count the distance and price of a trip from point A to B. You can try yourself by clicking 2 times in different parts of a map in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/EveGeen/wor9afo0/

```
ymaps.route([start, finish]).then(function (router) {
    var distance = Math.round(router.getLength() / 1000),
        message = '<span>Distance: ' + distance + 'km.</span><br/>' +
            '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Price: %sр.</span>';

    self._route = router.getPaths();

    self._route.options.set({ strokeWidth: 5, strokeColor: '0000ffff', opacity: 0.5 });
    self._map.geoObjects.add(self._route);
    self._start.properties.set('balloonContentBody', startBalloon + message.replace('%s', self.calculate(distance)));
    self._finish.properties.set('balloonContentBody', finishBalloon + message.replace('%s', self.calculate(distance)));

});
```

You will see that after A, B is set you can press on any of these letters and it will show distance and price.

How can I pass these two values (distance and price, lines 127-128) into two of my inputs at the top? I need only digits without text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id to the input elements :

```
<label>Distance:</label>
    <input id="dist" type="text" size="40" name="dist">
    <br>
    <label>Price:</label>
    <input id="price" type="text" size="40" name="price">
```

and add these set their value in `route` event this way:

```
document.getElementById("dist").value = distance; // distance here
document.getElementById("price").value = self.calculate(distance);// price here
```

You need to set the value of input elements in  `route` event :

```
ymaps.route([start, finish])
    .then(function (router) {
    var distance = Math.round(router.getLength() / 1000),
        message = '<span>Distance: ' + distance + 'km.</span><br/>' +
            '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Price: %sр.</span>';

    self._route = router.getPaths();

    self._route.options.set({
        strokeWidth: 5,
        strokeColor: '0000ffff',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    self._map.geoObjects.add(self._route);
    self._start.properties.set('balloonContentBody', startBalloon + message.replace('%s', self.calculate(distance)));
    self._finish.properties.set('balloonContentBody', finishBalloon + message.replace('%s', self.calculate(distance)));

    document.getElementById("dist").value = distance; // distance here
    document.getElementById("price").value = self.calculate(distance);// price here

   });
```

### WORKING DEMO:

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wor9afo0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='dist']")[0].value = distance; // distance
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='price']")[0].value = self.calculate(distance) // price
```